# Will 18.04 upgrade to a newer version of PHP?

Tags: 18.04, server, php

I understand that that `php` packages will receive security updates for the life of 18.04, but will the main repository ever include a newer version than 7.2?

Comment: No. See [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software) for the explanation of why.

Comment: @user535733 That is a terrible answer because the author doesn't make clear the difference between **packages** and **versions** and uses the words nearly interchangeably, which doesn't make sense from the perspective of `php`, but whatever.

Comment: feel free to improve that answer. You have that power.

Comment: @user535733 It is that kind of response that dissuades from contributing to this forum. The answers in that question do not answer my question. I asked my question because I do not know the answer to my question. Your comment assumes I know the answer to my question, or I can somehow derive the answer to my question from an answer that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: You asked a yes-or-no question: "*will the [18.04] main repository ever include a newer version than 7.2?*". The answer is "No." Since most folks follow up with "why?", I threw that link in as a bonus to keep the question clean and simple. You need not use that link. You don't need to derive anything. Most folks (but not everybody) finds that link helpful to understand this common question.